# Sharepoint / Intranet access to database

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, database-connection, intranet, powerapps

I have what I thought to be a rather simple task - to implement a small / un-complex database application that users should be able to read / write using an easy-to-use interface, to be made available for lots of users via Sharepoint or our Intranet.

I'm somewhat familiar with coding and databases, but I had hoped for a no-coding-required solution, like just using a microsoft product such as Power Apps (but that does not seem to work with Desktop layouts). And for so many reasons, I'd not like to use Ms Access. As it's so easy to connect to a SQL database in Power BI, I assumed that there should be an application that could actually WRITE into the database as well. Right?

I realize that this is a rather vague and broad question, but I have no idea where to start ... does anyone have any tips on where to start looking?

Comment: Why not just go with an Access web app? See [this video tutorial](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Create-an-Access-web-app-10855ec0-3a12-4e6c-a67c-c88267f00a3c)

Comment: Web apps are being discontinued and support withdrawn - see https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_access_support_team_blog/2017/03/31/access-web-apps-to-be-retired/ so I would not go down that route I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

the phrase: 'Lots of users' may indicate it needs to be browser based if they are geographically spread apart.  So potentially a web development project or subscribe to some sort of web service out there like Knack or AirTable.

You could consider Access runtime - very viable for Windows organization and if everyone is on the same LAN (or VPN).  It can front end to SQL Server without a problem.  The issue is that it is PC-based database and so it is all about the payload i.e. the quantity of records.

An open SharePoint List potentially could be used - everyone just writes into it - though there is no control.

Anytime a lot of users need to write into a common database - it's not going to be simple but it is definitely do-able but you need to establish the parameters in order to go with the correct platform.

Comment: The application needs to be available on the Intranet for widely spread users, hence web-based. Also, it needs to be hosted either in the cloud (Azure?) or in our virtual environment, so a PC based solution is not viable. I've got a SQL DB set up for this, so it's more of a matter of how to access the database from within some sort of web-based application. Initially, I thought of using a Sharepoint list, but it does not cover the needs of user-friendliness (it should be extremely easy to use, using some kind of forms). Gah!